# Raspberry pi Kodi Broken scrapers

Tags: kodi, osmc

I recently tried to add a Music Video to my library on my Raspberry pi running Kodi (more specifically OSMC) and could not get it to add it to the library. After doing some research and hours of tinkering here is what I found:

My first thought was that the internet was down so I ssh into the pi and try pinging google. when I got that to work I moved on to using the following terminal command to view the kodi error log.

```
tail -F /home/osmc/.kodi/temp/kodi.lo^C
```

what I found was that the movie database scraper wasn’t able to access tmdb.com so I copied and pasted the URL into my browser and saw that for some reason the API key was suspended. so I tried using the universal movie scraper to no avail. finally, I just tried scraping from local data but then the same thing happened when it got to the TV Show scraper and then also the music video scraper. unless all three of these are using the same scraper I find it suspect that all three would be failing at the same time. I have exhausted all of the troubleshooting options I can think of and that’s why I’m looking to the internet for help.

here is the log file for my setup:
[osmc Log](http://paste.osmc.tv/uhunefesoh)

hopefully you guys can find something that I couldn’t

Comment: Perhaps you need to update OSMC? From what I've read on Kodi forums, it could well be that the OSMC you have is running a Kodi version with suspended keys

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention in the post that as a part of my troubleshooting process I updated OSMC.

Comment: perhaps Sam Nazarko needs to update something in OSMC in that case